# htaccess rewrite rule/condition gives file not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I am trying..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)/__ver([0-9]+)__/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

What I am ultimately trying to do is version my file structure without actually changing the physical directory structure. I am also trying to set something up that will help prevent caching in some browsers. Either way I am basing this logic off of trying to remove the index.php from the URL with codeigniter but am failing.

I want to be able to in my html provide a uri in the `src=""` like

```
http://example.com/__ver333__/js/script.js
http://example.com/__ver333__/script.js
http://example.com/__ver333__/js/dir/script.js

or 

__ver333__/js/script.js
__ver333__/script.js
__ver333__/js/dir/script.js
```

but as far as the server acts or is concerned I want it to remove the **ver333** and pull the file accordingly. So its the equivilant of `http://example.com/js/script.js` or `/js/script.js`

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html, search for RewriteRule backreferences

Comment: What's wrong with the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724917/htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-prevent-caching-of-css-js-image-files

Comment: Its not working, for what I need it.. and revisiting it I feel I poorly conveyed the need so rather than do a massive edit that would change the whole thing I opened another question. The other one would serve purpose for other needs. But on that post for what I am trying to do it returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)/__ver([0-9]+)__/(.*)$` does not mean anything. `$1` is the first capture group in the regex in the first argument on that line. As this is the first argument, you are currently matching a file path against the characters `$1`. This will obviously never match.

What you want can easily be done with a regular rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/__ver[0-9]+__/(.*)$ /$1/$2
```

Make sure that you enable the `RewriteEngine` and set `RewriteBase /`.